# Can not export Cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

When I execute the next query in my neo4j web ui (localhost:7474/browser) `export-cypher -o export.cypher MATCH (n:COLUMN)-[r:LINK_REL_2]->() return n,r` query I get the next exception:

[image]

*What's wrong? How to dump?*

P.S. I'm using Neo4J v2.2.3

Answer (score 3):

`export.cypher` is not a valid thing in Cypher language and therefore cannot be executed from Neo4j browser. I guess you're referring to https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools. This can only be called via `bin/neo4j-shell`.